# Jquery $.get is unaccesible

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this mark up and a `json.txt` file which lies on the same directory as this .im unable to fetch it contents..also im not getting any errors in my firebug

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>   
     <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $.get('/json.txt', 
       function(data) { 
            $('div.result').html(data);

        });
     });
     </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="result"></div>
    </body>         
    </html>
```

Comment: Check the network tab. Is there a 404?

Comment: What happens if you log the output of data to the console?

Comment: Can you see the json.txt contents if you access it directly in the browser?

Comment: yes i can view @hsalama no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"on the same page" ? Do you mean "in the same directory" ? If so use

```
$.get('json.txt'
```

If this doesn't work, I suggest using the long form to see what happens :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'json.txt',
  success: function(data){console.log(data)},
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)};
});
```

So you can see in your console (ctrl+maj+i) the error (or the data).

Another note : this can't work if you're opening the html file in `file://` as the json would be considered coming from another domain. You must have an http server and open it in `http://`.

Comment: Are you running on `localhost` or are you just using the `file:///` protocol?

Comment: file:/// protocol  @ChrisFrancis

Comment: Ahhhh great..new thing learned today thanks for the support all

Comment: No problem. That's a tricky one to debug until you know the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you type full path, everything works?

```
$.get('http://localhost/json.txt', function(data) {

});
```

I am trying help to detect problem

If file is local (`file:///`), then look [jQuery: read text file from file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408707/jquery-read-text-file-from-file-system)