# jQuery click and load function do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, load

I'm trying to load text from a txt document to a div using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#contenthere').load('Load.txt');
    });
});
```

html:

```
<button> click me! </button>
<div id="contenthere">//Load.txt should load here!</div>
```

txt:

`If this text is loaded then you've managed to succefully use jQuery!`

The click function is working but the load function isn't working at all and I've tried different approaches towards this problem without success, and the Load.txt file is in the same folder as the index file were the jquery load code is stored!

**Edit:
Here's the error i got:**

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load      file:///C:/Users/nti/Google%20Drive/Gr%C3%A4nssnittsdesign/slutUppgift/exempel/Load.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

I also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "Load.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            succes : function (data){
                $("#contenthere").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And got the same error as above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: read text file from file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408707/jquery-read-text-file-from-file-system)

Comment: @ preyerguilt what is error on`console`

Comment: You cannot use AJAX from `file://` (though this might work in some older browsers). You need a `http://` environment for this to work, means calling `Load.txt` from a localhost or your server.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works fine, make sure you've the right permissions to read the file. Also, check what the console is outputting.

Comment: @ozil I've written the error in the question edit

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Your answer worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code to work, the problem must have been that i tried to use file:// instead of http:// so I loaded the page up to a Webb host and got the code working!