# how to work with ajax load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm making navigation and trying to load the data on the same page with

```
load()
```

but its giving me error when i click one of the links

[image]

i've got two page named about.html and contact.html

My HTML

```
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="about.html">About me</a>
  <div class="wrap"></div>
```

I was trying

```
  (function(){  

    $('a').on('click',function( e ){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.wrap').load(href);
        e.preventDefault();
    });

})();
```

Comment: try working with a webserver (`http://localhost....`) instead of browsing a file directly (`file://...`)

Comment: remove the `e` from `function(e)` and `e.preventDefault();`. Then try again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: read text file from file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408707/jquery-read-text-file-from-file-system)

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski That wouldn't solve the problem, and would throw another error instead.

Comment: You get cross origin requests issue when you're trying to load a resource other then your own webpage host. So, as @geevee said, if you try opening your page over localhost, over http:// , then you will not face this issue.

Comment: @Juhana hmm. Really? What's the cause of the throwing error?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski `preventDefault()` is not a global function. It's a member of the event object.

Comment: Open the webpage using a webserver. If you directly open the file with your browser, that won't work.