# $.get() does not work properly when running from local file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, readfile

I had some Javascript code to read a file. I open this file from my local file system in a browser:

```
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", "test.txt", false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
            findWord(rawFile.responseText.split("\n"));
        }
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
```

This works just fine, but it's deprecated in Chrome. After that discovery I tried to use `$.get()` like so:

```
$.get("test.txt", function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

But it doesn't even alert.

Is there a way to read this file in both Chrome and Firefox? Note that I don't want to use any kind of `<input type="file">` and the text data must be returned in an array of lines form the file.

I'm getting a warning and error from Chrome When using `$.get()` and `$.ajax()`.

Error:

> index.html:36 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/mz/Dropbox/Shubs/test.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I'm also not running on a server. So localhost doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Do you have any error on dev console ?

Comment: @IceManSpy Yes, wait a second, editing my post

Comment: `$.get` won't work over `file:///`. Consider not doing AJAX for things on your local filesystem.

Comment: are you using MVC or ASP.net ?

Comment: @apokryfos So, how do I gotta load the file then?

Comment: @SunilKumar Just plain HTML, JS and JQuery

Comment: @MZeinstra the way you used to load it and ignore the deprecation warning. You're doing things locally anyway so you can control the client side environment.

Comment: Unless you plan to deploy this to a server someday where someone else can use it, in which case you should not ignore that deprecation warning.

Comment: @DanielBeck Okay, so the warning doesn't matter, but I'm still getting this error..

Comment: To clarify, I meant continue doing this via `XMLHTTPRequest`. Long-term, if this is strictly happening on local you should really convert the script to something like Python if all you need to do is process text contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: read text file from file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408707/jquery-read-text-file-from-file-system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting :

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource error

becaure you're loading the file using **file://** or **C:/**, which stays true to the error message as they are not **http://** so i have two solutions to suggest to you :

1. either you send the file from a server (php,nodejs) and catch it in
   the client (ajax)
2. or you read the text file using the js file reader

Comment: The second answer doesn't match my requirements.. You'll have to use `<input type="file">` for FileReader

Comment: and why not use it ?

Comment: Because I don't want to select the same file every time I open the page

Comment: so i think u must consider my first solution,simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without server?

Comment: Okay I uploaded it to dropbox.. So I'm using an url with https, but that doesn't work either.. : `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4v91tiisv5n1sa/test.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Dropbox isn't a web host, they do not want you serving pages from their servers, so they do not (and will not) set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the resources they display. You need to run your own web server to solve this issue, either locally (i.e. running one on your PC - if you're on Windows you have IIS at your finger tips, and on Linux you have Apache) or pay for someone to host if for you and FTP the files to it ($2-3 a month)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
$.ajax({
            url: "test.txt",
            async: false,
            success: function (data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Then check your browser's console.

Comment: Yep, getting this error: `jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/mz/Dropbox/Shubs/test.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

Comment: can you try something in the url like `text.txt&callback=?`

Comment: Your answer is right there, you're asking the browser to `get` a file using the `file://` protocol and it's (rightly) saying "no". If you put your page on a webserver (e.g. IIS, Apache) and ran it from there (e.g. `http://localhost/index.html`) it would probably work fine.

Comment: Adding params to the URL would not change anything; file:// urls are disallowed for ajax requests.    (also note that `async:false` is deprecated, because freezing the whole browser to wait for an ajax call to return is kinda not great UX)

Comment: i'm using it for myself.. So I do not want to use a server.

Comment: @MZeinstra we use ajax methods to communicate from Client end to the Server! So, please try using some absolute URL `http://localhost/yourProject/yourfolder/test.txt`